# I didn't get the Pacifist ending, what went wrong?

Tags: undertale

What am I supposed to do to get the true Pacifist ending? I spared every monster I met but then when I got to the ending Toriel didn't come and save me like she does in the true pacifist route. I restarted my game but I found it really hard to complete up to where I got to previously.

What did I do wrong? Why didn't I get the true Pacifist ending?

Comment: Had you experienced the neutral ending first?

Answer (score 7):

To get the pacifist ending, you need to do the following:

- Reach the final fight without killing anyone. You must have earned no EXP at all
- Befriend Papyrus, if you haven't already. To do this, go to his house and complete the "date" with him
- Befriend Undyne by hanging out with her at her house after sparing her. This is only an option if you gave her water after she collapsed in Hotland
- Beat the game once, with the neutral ending (this doesn't have to be in the same run)

Backtrack out of The Core so your phone works. If you have done everything you need to, Undyne will call you and ask you to deliver a letter, starting the quest for the pacifist run.

> Deliver the letter, complete the date with Alphys, and explore the true laboratory.

Once you have done this, return to Asgore to begin the final pacifist battle.

Answer (score -2):

Be sure to have resetted after a neutral run. To make this easier, kill Asgore then reset then go on a pacifist. When you reach Asgore, go back to the entrance of the Core. If you have done everything correctly, you should receive a call from Undyne asking you to deliver a letter. Go to her and receive the letter then 
give it to Alphys in the lab. you should see a note telling you to enter the 'toilet' and when you do so, you will enter the true lab. Explore the place and exit safely then return to Asgore where Toriel will save you.